# How can I add Checkbox to GridView?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this Gridview

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvValues" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnRowCommand="gvValues_RowCommand"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" PageSize="15" ItemType="Product" CssClass="table-striped table-condensed table table-bordered table-hover"
  OnRowDataBound="gvValues_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvValues_PageIndexChanging" meta:resourcekey="gvValuesResource1" EmptyDataText="No Products in your Pos">
 <EmptyDataRowStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="16pt" ForeColor="Red" />
      <RowStyle Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
            <ItemTemplate><%# gvValues.PageSize*gvValues.PageIndex+ Container.DisplayIndex+1  %> 
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProduct" runat="server" CssClass="chkProduct"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="online" meta:resourcekey="Online">
         <ItemTemplate > 
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProductonline" runat="server"  />
          </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

I handle it using c# 
as

```
  products = GetProduct();    
  gvValues.DataSource = products;
  gvValues.DataBind();
```

Now I need to check checkbox `chkProductonline` depending on reading from Products list if `product.on` is  1 check the check box

how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `add checkbox`?  Isn't it already in the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gvValues_RowDataBound method (in code behind), you can get the checkbox control and populate it from the current data item. It's generally a good idea to check the current row type to make sure you're not in a header row, footer row, etc. since you only want to do this for actual item rows. It would look something like this:

```
private void gvValues_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure current row is a data row (not header, footer, etc.)
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Get checkbox control
       var chkProductonline= e.Row.FindControl("chkProductonline") as CheckBox;

       // Get data item (recommend adding some error checking here to make sure it's really a Product)
       var product = e.Row.DataItem as Product

       // Set checkbox checked attribute
       chkProductonline.Checked = product.on;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Very much , Could you help me what if I need to Know the check box Value of the `chkProduct` on `chkProductonline_CheckedChanged`

Comment: Events that trigger post backs, like CheckedChanged, are tricky within repeaters, grid views, etc. If all you need is a client-side event (execute some JavaScript for instance), then that's easy enough. However, if you need to post back when a checkbox inside a repeater changes, then that's a different story. I'd probably start by creating a Command Column and configure one of the buttons to call a method in code behind that does whatever you need done when the checkbox changes. Then use CSS and JS to hide that column and click the button when the checkbox changes.

Comment: I am Soryy I didn't understand you 
` protected void chkProductonline_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var chkProductonline = FindControl("chkProductonline") as CheckBox;
           bool ischeck = chkProductonline.Checked;
            var chkProduct = FindControl("chkProduct") as CheckBox;
            string vali = chkProduct.ClientID;
        }`
I need to know if the online checked or not and the value of another checkbox

Comment: You can't just get **the** `chkProductonline` checkbox for the page, since there are multiple (one per row). You'd have to get the one from the row that was clicked on. Unfortunately, that information isn't passed to your code-behind. I'd look into using a CommandColumn, which can pass a row ID, or the ID of your data item when it performs the post back. From there, you can get the row in the gridview and get controls from it.